# How to prove the product of first n consecutive odd numbers is a square less than another square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction, products

I have observed for first few values of consecutive odd numbers, the result is always of the form:

$m^2 - n^2$, where $m$ and $n$ are two distinct positive integers. That is:
$$1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot 7\cdots (2k-1) = m^2 - n^2$$

For example:

$
1\cdot 3 = 3 = 2^2 - 1^2 \\
1\cdot 3\cdot 5 = 15 = 4^2 - 1^2 \\
1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 105 = 11^2 - 4^2 \\
1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9 = 945 = 31^2 - 4^2 \\
\vdots
$

But not sure, how to prove it.
Here is an attempt using induction:

Let it be true for some value of k, that is:
$1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdots(2k - 1) = m^2 - n^2$

Then when $k$ takes the value of $k+1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdots(2k - 1)\cdot(2k + 1)
&= (m^2 - n^2)\cdot(2k + 1)\\
&= (m^2 - n^2)\cdot {(k+1)^2 - k^2}
\end{align}$$
and got stuck here.

Can you please suggest to proceed further or an altogether a different way of proving so or prove me wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any odd number is the difference of two (consecutive) squares. $2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2$.

Comment: Yes @AndreasBlass any odd number is the difference of two consecutive squares.  However, in this case the differences are among non-consecutive squares (except the first one). Hence requesting for a proof / counter example.

Comment: My comment is a proof, unless you change the question to require non-consecutive $m$ and $n$.

Comment: If you really want non-consecutive $m$ and $n$, then just observe that any odd number that is divisible by $3$ is necessarily of the form $6n+3$ and therefore the difference of non-consecutive squares $(n+2)^2-(n-1)^2$.

Comment: @KarriChandrasekhar to prove by induction, you have to use: $(a^2 - b^2)(c^2 - d^2) = (ac + bd)^2 - (ad + bc)^2$. But of course you have to prove that these two are not consecutive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that *any* product of two distinct odd numbers or two distinct even numbers can be written as a difference of squares. Let $p<q$ be both odd or both even.  Then $(q-p)/2$ and $(q+p)/2$ are distinct integers, and
$$
((q+p)/2)^2 - ((q-p)/2)^2=(q^2/4+pq/2+p^2/4)-(q^2/4-pq/2+p^2/4)=pq.
$$
So this is a fairly weak condition, and one that the product of consecutive odd numbers certainly meets.

Comment: The other answer is correct, of course... fixing $p=1$ shows that any odd number is the difference of consecutive squares.  For non-consecutive squares, you only need to stipulate $p>1$, which of course is still possible in OP's case.

Answer (score 0):

You might note that the difference sequence of the sequence of squares is exactly the odd numbers.  Here's the sequence of squares:

$$0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, \ldots$$

Here's the sequence of the differences:

$$1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, \ldots$$

That means every odd number is the difference of two *consecutive* squares.  And your number is odd.

Comment: Yes B.Goddard, any odd number is the difference of two consecutive squares.  However, in this case the differences are among non-consecutive squares (except the first one). Hence requesting for a proof / counter example.

Comment: @KarriChandrasekhar Then maybe you should re-word your question.  You say nothing about "non-consecutive."  So as it stands, your objection makes no sense.